# Determining starting points of accumulation points

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
var mostFrequentlyUsedEntriesOfList = inputList.GroupBy(word => word)
                      .Select(wordGroup => new { Word = wordGroup.Key, Frequency = wordGroup.Count() })
                      .OrderByDescending(word => word.Frequency);
```

Which creates objects having a Key and Frequency.

What do I have to add to the mostFrequentlyUsedEntriesOfList, to also have starting points of accumulation points? What I mean is this:

Example inputList:

```
a
a
b
b
a
a
b
b
a
b
b
b
b
b
a
```

Would result in

```
b 9
a 6
```

Starting point of accumulation points would be(counting the first item as 1)

```
b 10
```

So the starting point of b's occurrence is at position 10.

Altogether:

```
Word frequency position
b 9 10
a 6 1
```

Note: a starts at 1 and 5 with the same frequency, so choose the first of the same frequency.

If something is occuring only once, then this is the accumulation point, for instance if there was one c at the beginning:

```
c 1 1
```

What do I have to add to the mostFrequentlyUsedEntriesOfList, to also have starting points of accumulation points?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "accumulation points". I don't understand how the `10` relates to `b` as it's accumulation point.

Comment: Anyone else not understanding this?

Comment: Had to read it a few times, but I understand it now... get the **1-based starting point of the longest running sequence of each letter**. So for `b`, the longest running sequence is 5 and it starts at position `10`. For `a`, the longest running sequence is 2 and there are 2 occurrences, so just take the first which is at position `1`.

Comment: @davmos That's it. I did not perceive the task description to be challenging, but if there is a teacher among use, feel free to use it as a test question and report back with the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mostFrequentlyUsedEntriesOfList = inputList
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .Select(wordGroup => new
    {
        Word = wordGroup.Key,
        Frequency = wordGroup.Count(),
        Position = Enumerable.Range(0, inputList.Count())
            .OrderByDescending(index => inputList.Skip(index).TakeWhile(current => current == wordGroup.Key).Count())
            .First() + 1
    })
    .OrderByDescending(word => word.Frequency);
```

This finds the longest runs by iterating over all indexes, seeing how long the sequence runs from there, and selecting the index where it is maximal.

Comment: It should select the index where the accumulation starts, not where it's maximal.

Comment: Probably I should have worded it better. It doesn't select the maximal index, but the index where the longest sequence with the given items starts, just as davmos described it in the comments of your question.

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength Can you please finally accept this answer, it obviously does what you requested, and you obviously haven't even tried running it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Yes, I didn't have the time to run it, yet.